# cross image not appearing next to input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi I am trying to make an input text field with a cross icon in front of it. So that if user clicks cross that field gets removed. Right now I am using bootstrap class close over button tag. But the result is not coming. It needs to be done using bootstrap.

Here's my code:

```
         <div class="col-lg-7 ven" hidden="hidden">
            <label for="vendor" >Vendor</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="vendor" placeholder="Enter Vendor" name="vendor" value="not defined">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
           </div>
```

Output right now:

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap docs shows you how to place an icon over an input: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-control-validation

Comment: I have to place cross sign in front of text box not inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-7 ven">
     <label for="vendor" >Vendor</label>
   <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm ">
   
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="vendor" placeholder="Enter Vendor" name="vendor" value="not defined">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
  <span class="input-group-addon">&times;</span></button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

In my opinion, you should use the class [`.input-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) by Bootstrap. It solves your issue.

Your final code would look like this given above.

Use this code with Bootstrap and you are good to go.
I hope I might be of help.